# how to use proxy in selenium 4.1

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

i am trying to make an automation project which will use proxy to register in a site. but i am unable to get it work.

I have tried selenium-wire for proxy authentication still it doesn't work

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import os
import keyboard
import pyautogui
from time import sleep


user = 'jesbeqki'
pwd = '1wbt8dnqtu8w'
end = '2.56.119.93:5074'

seleniumwire_options ={
    "proxies" : {
    "https": "http://"f"{user}:{pwd}@{end}/",
    "http": "http://"f"{user}:{pwd}@{end}/",
    'verify_ssl': False
}
}
firefox_options = Options()
# firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options)

driver.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')

text = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').text
print(text)
```

it's showing my original ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to proxy to a site.

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run this with `python` after filling in the proxy details:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, proxy="USER:PASS@IP:PORT") as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://whatismyip.com")
    sb.sleep(5)
```

Comment: what if i dont have a user or pass only ip and port bec its public? it doesnt work when i do ip:port any site says {domain} did not respond smth like that

Comment: `proxy="IP:PORT"` format should work as long as your proxy is valid.

Comment: the ip and port work for requests and ipinfo but when i use SB it always says example.com took too long to respond

Comment: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.
Site couldnt be reached
whatismyip.com took too long to respond.
```python
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, proxy="IP:PORT") as sb:
    sb.sleep(10)
    sb.driver.get("https://whatismyip.com")
    sb.sleep(10)
```

Comment: but this works:
```python
import requests
proxies = {"http": "http://IP:PORT"}
response = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/json", proxies=proxies)
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the proxy config like this:

```
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy["ip"]}:{proxy["port"]}')
```